# How to inject a handler into a custom BaseHTTPRequestHandler instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a link on how to create a custom web server:
https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/http.server.html

Basically

```
def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

No Problem, I derive from `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` and create my custom http request handler who is responsible for proper http replies.

But what would be the best way to actually inject a behaviour into my request handler? The handler itself should know how to format a given reply (e.g. html, xml, json, etc) but should actually not know what to do with a request itself.

Normally I would do something like this

```
handler = MyRequestHandler()
handler.processor = SomeProcessor() # or ctor injection etc

run(HTTPServer, handler )
```

Which I obviously cannot do because you only pass a type into the server and on each finish_request of BaseServer it gets created:

```
def finish_request(self, request, client_address):
    """Finish one request by instantiating RequestHandlerClass."""
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
```

Is the only way of passing things to actually derive from `HTTPServer` and override `finish_request`? Because I couldn't find any further use of the handler (`self.RequestHandlerClass`).

I am a python noob so I might miss something obvious here (also would like to avoid hard-code the process behaviour because I still might need some context later (like other instances))